# Ограничить доступ по урлу

Tags: yii2

Есть три роли юзеров. RBAC пока не хочу юзать, поэтому вопрос: как правтльно отграничить доступ одной роли к интерфейсу другой?

Урлы у меня имеют такие виды:

site.ru/role1/info, site.ru/role2/info, site.ru/role3/info

Вот надо сделать так, чтоб незарег, role2, role2, role3 при переходе по урлу site.ru/role1/info получали "Доступ запрещён"

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать свои классы пользователей и ролей и по ним определять доступ в контроллере.

Например, через `matchcallback`:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'allow' => true,
        'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
            if (($action->id != 'index') 
               && ($action->id != 'view') 
               && ($action->id != 'status')) {
                return (! Yii::$app->user->isGuest) 
                  && ((Users::findIdentity(Users::findIdentity(Yii::$app->user->id)->isAdmin())) 
                  || (Users::findIdentity(Users::findIdentity(Yii::$app->user->id)->isManager())));
          } else {
              return (! Yii::$app->user->isGuest);
          }
      },
      'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
           return $this->redirect([
               'site/login'
           ]);
      }
   ]
]
```

Полный пример можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/Streletz/tasktracker/blob/1.0/models/User.php).